# react-native-inline-edit syntax issue

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using the 'react-native-inline-edit' in my app, but getting an error:

```
SyntaxError in /Users/evarina077/Documents  
/08_almostEditRN/components/EditPlugin.js: Unexpected 
token (19:31)
  17 |       <Text>Testing</Text>
  18 |       <EditableText
> 19 |         text={'textOfTheField'},
     |                                ^
  20 |         sendText={() => sendText()},
  21 | 
  22 |         loading: isLoading,
```

I'm getting this error, but not sure why the "," would be an error, don't I need that?

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need the commas there. The values such as `text`, `sendText` etc are props, and they are not comma-separated. This would do:

```
<EditableText
  text={'textOfTheField'}
  sendText={() => sendText()}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are inside an XML markup element, `<EditableText>` you can't use commas to separate different attributes.  That's invalid syntax.

When you're in JSX/XML elements context, you have to adhere to JSX/XML syntax.

In braces within JSX/XML elements `{}` you drop back in to JS syntax.